# How to call Datagridview cell double click event from a button?

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to call  datagridview cell event method from an another button.

**DataGridView Cell Double Click Method**

```
private void ListDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.RowIndex >= 0)
            {
                ListDataGridView.SelectionMode = DataGridViewSelectionMode.FullRowSelect;
                DataGridViewRow row = this.ListDataGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

                comboBox2.Text = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

            }
        }
```

**This is Button where I'm calling this method**

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ListDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender, e);
}
```

**Error I'm receiving**

> Error 3   The type or namespace name 'DataGridViewCellEventHandler' does
>   not exist in the namespace 'System' (are you missing an assembly
>   reference?)   C:\VisualC#\Projects\DataGridViewApplication\DataGridViewApplication\List.Designer.cs   340 46  DataGridViewApplication

**What I did:**

I changed EventArgs to DataGridViewCellEventArgs.

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
   {    
     ListDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender, e);
   }
```

Now I'm receiving Error:

```
this.button6.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button6_Click);
```

> Error 3   No overload for 'button6_Click' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'
>
> C:\VisualC#\Projects\DataGridViewApplication\DataGridViewApplication\List.Designer.cs 340 35  DataGridViewApplication

**Now I changed button event handler code to this**

```
this.button6.Click += new System.DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.button6_Click);
```

**Still Receiving this error and stucked here**

> Error 3   No overload for 'button6_Click' matches delegate
>   'System.EventHandler'

**Found a solution here:**
[How to call a datagridview event with a click of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838861/how-to-call-a-datagridview-event-with-a-click-of-a-button)

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(null, null);  
        }
```

but this is not working for me, it gives me an error.

> Object Reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: As another option instead of trying to call event handler of `CellDoubleClick`, you can put the logic in method like `DoSomething` and call it in both `CellDoubleClick` event and `Click` event of your button. For example, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38611739/3110834).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
    private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        ListDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(this.ListDataGridView, new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(this.ListDataGridView.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex,this.ListDataGridView.CurrentRow.Index));

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you have this at the top of you Form.cs file:

```
using  System.Windows.Forms;
```

Eventhandlers are strongly typed, so both event and handler need to have matching types.

The `Click` eventhandler requires a method signature of `void(object sender, EventArgs e)` so your initial code was the right approach:

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // create and set values for the event argument. 
  // it can't be EventArgs, so just instantiate the right type
  // the constructor needs a row and column
  var datagridviewArgs = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(42,13);
  ListDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(sender, datagridviewArgs);
}
```

but as you can see you need to provide the correct type for the second parameter, the [DataGridViewCellEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcelleventargs.datagridviewcelleventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), on the call to `ListDataGridView_CellDoubleClick`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this...

```
private void btnChoose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    MouseEventArgs b = new MouseEventArgs(System.Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left, 2, 
        MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, 0);
    DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs a = new DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs(0, 0, 
        MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y, b);
    dataGridView1_CellMouseDoubleClick(sender, a);
}
```